# Laravel 4 - 2 forms with the same input names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created 2 separate forms. One for signin and one for signup. They work fine on separate pages but if they are on the same page they print each others error messages. I'm guess its because they both contain the same input names.

They have separate controller methods though. Here is the example setup.

**Signup form**

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'signup']) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
    {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    {{ $errors->first('email', '<p class="error">:message</p>')}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password','Paswword') }}
    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    <p class="help-block">Password needs to be between 6 - 8 characters</p>
    {{ $errors->first('password', '<p class="error">:message</p>')}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">

    {{ Form::submit('Sign up', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Login form**

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'login']) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
    {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    {{ $errors->first('email', '<p class="error">:message</p>')}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password','Paswword') }}
    {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    {{ $errors->first('password', '<p class="error">:message</p>')}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">

    {{ Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/signup', [
    'as' => 'signup',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@getSignup'
]);
Route::post('/signup', [
    'as' => 'signup',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@postSignup'
]);
```

Just wondering if anyone else has come across this issue and how to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#error-messages-and-views

> **Named Error Bags**
>
> If you have multiple forms on a single page, you may wish to name the MessageBag of errors. This will allow you to retrieve the error messages for a specific form. Simply pass a name as the second argument to withErrors:
>
> ```
> return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
> ```
>
> You may then access the named MessageBag instance from the $errors variable:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $errors->login->first('email'); ?>
> ```

Comment: @KarolFiturski I'm not aware of a solution there, other than ensuring each field has a unique identifier.

Comment: When I change these then I have to change the corresponding column names in Eloquent... Am I right?

Comment: @KarolFiturski Not necessarily. You could rename them before saving the model. i.e. `$model->name = Input::get('notName');`